# HttpWebRequest зависает и не слушает Timeout

Tags: c#, http, proxy, httpwebrequest

Пытаюсь делать Get запросы при помощи класса `HttpWebRequest`. В большинстве случаев все ок, но, иногда происходит зависание и поток в котором совершается запрос замораживается. Я делаю запросы через прокси и заметил, что зависания происходят только на некоторых адресах. Таймауты, которые я задал не всегда учитываются( Каким образом можно ограничить еще время совершения запроса через прокси? Как избежать зависания - 100%?

`(HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse()` - код доходит до этого момента и поток зависает.

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);

    request.Method = "GET";



    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0";
    request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest");
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.Host = "www.instagram.com";
    request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;


    request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    request.Headers.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
    request.Headers.Add("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1");
    request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

    //тАЙМАУТЫ
    request.Timeout = 1500;
    request.ReadWriteTimeout = 1500;
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    request.Proxy = proxy;


    string result = "";

    using (HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.GetEncoding(httpWebResponse.CharacterSet)))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }


    request.Abort();
    httpWebResponse.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем много времени прошло с момента, как я задал этот вопрос, но хочу оставить пометку себе в прошлом. Возможно, кому-то поможет.

- Убедитесь в том, что все объекты типа `HttpWebResponse и
  HttpWebRequest` очищены после их использования. Для этого идеально
  подходит конструкция `using` для `HttpWebResponse` и вызов метода
  `Abort` для `HttpWebRequest`. Почему-то, если не закрыть соединение, то есть вероятность, что попытка осуществить следующий запрос - зависнет. Таймауты в таких случаях программа игнорирует. (Я не знаю почему так, но точно знаю, что помогает закрытие и очистка соединений)
- Используйте конструкцию `try finally` для вызова метода `Abort`
  `HttpWebRequest`, так как HttpWebRequest не реализует `IDisposable`
  интерфейс.
- Убедитесь, что все приложения для мониторинга траффика работают корректно (если вы их используете). Если у Вас какие-то проблемы, то попробуйте отключить программы подобного рода.

***Простой пример, который должен работать стабильно и будет безопасным:***

```
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://google.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
        request.Method = "GET";

        try
        {
            //Используем констуркцию using для объекта типа HttpWebResponse. Это гарантия того, что метод Close будет вызван даже если код выдаст исключение (Читайте подробнее про IDisposable и конструкцию using)
            using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream);
                var responseHtml = sr.ReadToEnd(); //Тело ответа
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            request?.Abort(); //Если request не равен null, то вызываем метод Abort.
        }
```